# Hide listing of all childfolders in parent folder but show childfolder's content

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hide listing of all childfolders in parent folder but show childfolder's content, or simply writing something like below in the .htaccess of parent folder...

```
IndexIgnore * (except childfolders+their content)
```

**Directory structure:**

```
parent >

child 1->something.pdf
child 2->anything.pdf
...
...
child n->another-something.pdf
```

now to the user when he goes to *parent*, then nothing should be visible but when he goes to `parent/child [1 to n]/`  he should see the *corresponding pdf*.

(also childfolders are *dynamically generated* and are *very large in number* !)

Comment: Can you describe more by giving some examples of what should be allowed and what shouldn't be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in `parent/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
```

Comment: Yes only parent is forbidden not children.